# sublime text2 package control cannit find any package for installation

Tags: package, sublimetext

I am using sublime text2 on windows 7 64bit. And I installed package control successfully, then I use ctrl + alt + P and I entered :install package, then I got the error .

```
Package Control: Error downloading channel. 
URL error [Errno 10060] A connection attempt  failed 
because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, 
or established connection failed 
because connected host has failed to respond downloading https://sublime.wbond.net/repositories.json.

error: Package Control: There are no packages available for installation.
```

it seems that I cannot access to the server, do I need to set proxy or make some network setting ?

Comment: Were you able to fix your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, just set the `http_proxy` and `https_proxy` variables in `Package Control Settings`. The stub is already given. The formats should be as follows,

```
http://username:password@proxyHost:proxyPort
```

and

```
https://username:password@proxyHost:proxyPort
```

The `username:password` bit is optional.